# glClearColor() doesnt change the background color

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es

I tried to render some OpenGL stuff with Qt's OpenGL widget. After having trouble with not getting anything displayed, I only tried to change the background color of the window to something else than black. But even this is not happening.

Has this something to do with Qt or am I messing up the OpenGL stuff?

Here is some of the code I wrote:

```
class GLWidget2 : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLExtraFunctions
{
public:
    GLWidget2(QWidget* parent = 0);

    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);
    void initializeGL();
};
GLWidget2::GLWidget2(QWidget* parent) :
    QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    QSurfaceFormat format;

    //doesn't set the background color
   format.setVersion(3, 0);

   //sets the background color
   //format.setVersion(2, 0);

    setFormat(format);
}

void GLWidget2::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    qDebug() << (char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION) << "\n";
}

void GLWidget2::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void GLWidget2::resizeGL(int width, int heigth)
{
    update();
}
```

I'm running on a **OpenGL 3.0 ES** platform because of some driver issues.

EDIT:

If I change the OpenGL version QOpenGLWidget is using to OpenGL 2.0 ES everything is working fine. But I really don't want to use OpenGL 2.0.
I can't figure out what should cause this problem in 3.0

EDIT2:

changed the code to a smaller example

Comment: @tobin-thomas: If you edit questions, make sure you fix **all** major problems. Just marking some things in bold is not helpful if you don't fix capitalizations and code formatting in the same step.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with C++? There isn't something specific to C++, only to qt and opengl?

Comment: This is how it was at the beginning. Forgot to reverse that change. So this doesn't change anything.

Comment: Is it possible that with OpenGL 3.0 ES glClearColor() has no effect anymore? The documention says there is glClearColor but when I'm changing too OpenGL 2.0 ES glClearColor() seems to work.

Comment: Are you even using opengl-es? From what I see you request a desktop GL 3.0 context. (and the compatibility profile hint looks fishy since profiles were introduced in 3.2, in opengl-es there is no such thing as a profile).

Comment: glGetString(GL_VERSION) says OpenGL ES 3.0 (ANGLE 2.1.99f075dade7c)